# Shorter proof of measurability of the set where two measurable functions differ

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f,g$ be measurable functions from $\Omega$ into $[0,\infty]$. I want to show that the set where the two functions differ is measurable. i.e. the set $K = \{x\in \Omega: f(x) \neq g(x) \}$ is measurable. Since $f,g$ can take on $+\infty$, my approach is to consider the following cases:

For $x \in \Omega$ such that $f(x) \neq g(x)$,

1. $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$, $g(x) \in \mathbb{R}$
2. $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$, $g(x) = \infty$
3. $f(x)  = \infty $, $g(x) \in \mathbb{R}$

Since the cases 2 and 3 are symmetric, I essentially need to consider cases 1 and 2 (without loss of generality). But is there a shorter proof of the claim which handles all three cases all at once?

Comment: $K^C = (f-g)^{-1}(\{0\})$.

Comment: @JoeyZou How about when $f$ and $g$ take on $\infty$? Then, I would have $\infty-\infty$

Comment: Good point - I guess in that case you could "define" $f-g$ to be $0$ if both of them take on $\infty$, and proving that the resulting function is measurable wouldn't be too hard (but also wouldn't really be less work than you're looking for).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One idea is the following: Show that

$$
\Phi : [0,\infty] \to [0,1], x \mapsto \frac{x}{1+x} = 1 - \frac{1}{1+x}
$$
is strictly increasing and (thus) measurable with respect to the usual $\sigma$-algebras.

Now $\Phi \circ f, \Phi \circ g$ are both measurable with

$$
\{x \mid f(x) \neq g(x)\} = \{x \mid \Phi \circ f (x) \neq \Phi \circ g(x)\} = \{x \mid (\Phi \circ f - \Phi \circ g)(x) \neq 0\},
$$
which is measurable.

Note that the difference makes sense (and is measurable) since $\Phi \circ f, \Phi \circ g$ only take finite values.